# Subclipse: Merging from Trunk to Branch; No revisions are eligible for merge

Tags: svn, merge, subclipse

I'm trying to setup a branch of my main project. I have the branch created. I have my working copy(the branch) updated and checked out and I have the trunk updated and checked out.

I right click on my branch, the working copy and click Team > Merge. I then get the CollabNet Merge dialog. I choose Merge a range of revisions. I then hit next and it performs the pre-merge best practices. Once that's complete nothing happens and I'm able to hit next again. I hit next again and nothing happens except I get the message "No revisions are eligible for merge".

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you have trunk checked out.  I am going to ignore that.  You want to start with just your branch checked out.  In the merge dialog you do not say whether it already had /trunk entered as the path to merge from.  But that would need to be done.

Then in terms of revisions, well, have their been commits made to trunk since the branch was created?  If not, then there are no revisions to merge to the branch.  That seems to be what SVN is saying.

You do not even have to specify revisions, you can just say to merge all revisions and SVN will figure out what changes have happened in trunk since the revision the branch was created from.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the answer. I figured out the answer I posted below. It was a fundamental misunderstanding re repository roots on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening. I hope this will be of help to others.

When I checked out my projects from SVN I used 2 different repository root. My repository roots were:

- Trunk: http://someurl/project/trunk
- Branch:http://someurl/project/branch

With subclipse the repository roots are set during checkout, using the New Project wizard -> Checkout Projects from SVN. The dialog "Checkout from SVN" has create a new repository location and use existing repository location.

As I had picked 2 different repository roots on this screen SVN obviously didn't know that the branch and trunk were related. I deleted my projects and checked them out using the correct repository root i.e. http://someurl/project